# Chinese Speaking Gps Tracker For My Dog, please help to translate

Tags: translation, spoken

I bought a new Chinese GPS tracker for my dog online on eBay
I have some problem to configure it because I can't track it, I followed all the instruction in English but I can't figure out what 
is wrong

When I press on the only button it has and it speaks Chinese so I recorded it and want your help to translate it

I have two videos with different sentences:
https://youtu.be/xxJvdyaGVfA

https://youtu.be/9hmWyLZU-0o

the product link on ebay:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pet-Dogs-Cats-Sheep-Finder-Realtime-GPS-GSM-Tracker-Waterproof-For-Android-iOS/392097084010?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=661043181839&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Thank you,
Or Hirshfeld
Israel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first video is quite clear: she says,

> 3874成功
>   3874 succeeded

The second video is harder to decipher. It’s not Chinese; after listening a few times, I believe she says,

> Number not set.

Not sure if that tells you very much, but that appears to be the extent of it.